# media player hosted on aspx page does not SendPlayStateChangeEvents

Tags: javascript, html, wmp

I have an aspx page with Windows Media Player as an object on it.

When it finishes playing an audio file it is supposed to raise an event but it does not.
The page also includes Silverlight, which controls the player.

Here I add the event listener:

```
var slCtl = null;
var WMP = null;

function pluginLoaded(sender, args) {
  slCtl = sender.getHost();
  WMP = document.getElementById("wmp");
if (WMP.addEventListener) {
  WMP.addEventListener('playStateChange', sendPlayerStateToSL, false);
} else if (WMP.attachEvent) {
  WMP.attachEvent('playStateChange', sendPlayerStateToSL);
 }
}
```

Here we have the HTML for WMP

```
    <object id="wmp" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="audio/x-ms-wma" >
        <param name="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" value="True" />
        <param name="AutoStart" value="True" />
        <param name="PlayCount" value="1" />
        <param name="AutoSize" value="True" />
        <param name="uiMode" value="invisible" />
    </object>
```

I can start playing an audio file but when it finishes WMP does not raise an event and
sendPlayerStateToSL() is never run.

```
    function sendPlayerStateToSL() {
        switch (WMP.playState) {
            case 3:
                slCtl.Content.mySLapp.WmpStartedPlaying(WMP.playState, document.getElementById("wmp").currentMedia.durationString);
                break;
            case 8:
                if (document.getElementById("wmp").uiMode == "invisible")
                    slCtl.Content.mySLapp.WmpEndedPlaying(WMP.playState);
                else {
                    document.getElementById("wmp").uiMode = "invisible";
                    slCtl.Content.mySLapp.SetFocusToKennitala();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
```

What is strange is that this was working fine some months ago, but now it is like something has changed.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be broken on IE11:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811810/events-not-firing-on-wmp-object-in-ie11

Comment: The link also provides a workaround, although some comments suggest it might not work "Adding a compatibility mode works: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">"

Answer (score 0):

Putting the following in fixed the problem :)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```